# InnerHTML when no ID of element

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to grab the inner text of an element on a particular "group" of pages on my website. These pages, called "report pages" all have some common html that looks like this:

```
<!-- start report description -->
<div class="report-description-text">
<h5>Description</h5>
Hello World, here is a sample report.
<br/>
```

This is the html generated by the platform that I use. It's odd to me that the text starting "Hello World" is not contained in tags of it's own such as a `<p>` tag but that's what I have.

I am trying to create dynamic meta tags for search and social open graph. In this instance I'd like to grab the text "Hello World, here is a sample report" as a meta description.

The internet says use getElementsById but there is no ID here.

I've attached a screen of inspect element with Chrome that shows the selection.

How would I assign to a variable the afore mentioned text like so:

var descrptn = [what to I put here?]

to produce:
document.write(descrptn);

which would give 
Hello World, here is a sample report

You can see the actual sample page here: http://tinyurl.com/qxvm5y7

[image]

Comment: In my question I used "Hello World..." as an example, int he screenshot the corresponding text is "Welcome to Ushahidi..."

Comment: Thanks for the answers below, I'm grateful that you responded. Not that the answers are complex, they seem straightforwards enough, but it's not as simple as I'd expected.
I'm fiddling around int he console in Chrome and thinking back to a JS textbook I read a while back about navigating the DOM using dot notation.
I was expecting (and attempting) to use something along the lines of:
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text').h5.somethinghere
Does that sound right? Am I talking nonsense?

Comment: It is easier if you comment on the answers so that the authors can see them. However, you are correct in thinking that `getElementsByClassName` can be used here. However, [it has even sparser support than `querySelectorAll`](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/). Also, using dot notation is not something I have encountered anywhere except `forms` in some cases. Further, if it is not a constraint, you should consider using `jQuery` for such DOM manipulation tasks to get support for all browsers upto IE6.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to support only IE8+, then you can [safe(ish)ly](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/) use `.querySelectorAll` and then walk through the children to find the text node you are after:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.report-description-text');
var totalElems = elems.length;
for(var ii = 0; ii < totalElems; ii++) {
    if (elems[ii].childNodes && 
        elems[ii].childNodes.length >= 2 && 
        elems[ii].childNodes[1].nodeType === 3){ /* make sure it is a TEXT_NODE */

        description = elems[ii].nodeValue;
        document.write(description);
    }
}
```